# Add new Attributes to a HTML string with JQuery

Tags: jquery, string, attributes, new-operator, addition

i have a problem to add a new attribute to an existing html string.

First i read the HTML-code from a editor and save it as String.

Then i can acces attributes from this string with:

```
$("img", $(htmlString)).attr("src");
```

But if i try to add a new attribute (eg. name), it doesn't work.
To do this i try:

```
$("img", $(htmlString)).attr("name", "fooo");
```

So my problem is, that i need to add a new attribute with some value and at the end i should have a new HTML-string wich contains the old HTML code with the new added attributes.
I hope someone can help me.

Comment: I think you forgot to add a closing bracket.

Comment: What do you need the new attribute for? If you're just storing arbitrary information, the [`data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method is a better choice all around.

Comment: I want to copy the value from src, modify it, and save in a new attribute in the same img tag. Only the save part doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to copy the value from src, modify it, and save in a new attribute in the same img tag. Only the save part doesn't work

Try this:

```
var $img = $("img", $(htmlString));
var src = $img.attr("src");
src = src.replace(".jpg", ".png");
$img.attr("data-src", src);
```

This will turn this:

```
<img src="/images/myimage.jpg" alt="Example image" />
```

In to this:

```
<img src="/images/myimage.jpg" data-src="/images/myimage.png" alt="Example image" />
```

This is assuming there is only 1 `img` tag in `htmlString`. If you have more than one, you will need to loop through each one.

Comment: Thanks. I have one more question. is there only the img tag (<img src="/images/myimage.jpg" data-src="/images/myimage.png" alt="Example image" />) in the $img variable saved? Because my HTML code contains except img tags, other tags too.